# There is a jar file, but it indicates an error in oracle

Tags: java, ojdbc

The `ojdbc7.jar` file is located in `referenced libraries` and `lib`. However, `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is specified. What to do?

Also, wrote `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");`.

Comment: Try `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`

Comment: @g00se was the same :(

Comment: Possibly worth looking in to the jar to see if that class is present

Comment: Looks like your jar isn't in the classpath.

Comment: @jpllosa is this window/preferences/build path/classpath variables?

Comment: @jpllosa it contains jre_lib, jre_src, jre_srcroot and junit_home

Comment: Don't know about your setup but the classpath a way to tell applications, including the JDK tools, where to look for user classes. In the command line it goes something like this `java -classpath C:\myclasses`. In an IDE, should be somewhere in Build/Run > Configuration or something like that.

Comment: aa it's eclipse @jpllosa

Comment: @g00se - Just to be clear: since Java 5, you don't *need* to use `Class.forName` to load a JDBC driver.  (And in some circumstances, it a bad thing to do.) Instead you should use `DriverManager` and let it discover the drivers from the runtime classpath.  (Assuming that the driver JAR is on the runtime classpath ... which is what the OP's real problem was.)

Comment: @Stephen C I'm aware of that, My comment was made for diagnostic purposes only

Answer (score 0):

It's me.
It's just that when I export the `jar file`, click `runnable jar` and select `package required libraries into generated JAR`. Thank you guys.